# How to set the value of a Double/Integer type of a java class by JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

Earlier, I ask a question as:

[How can I set the value of “Double” type variable of my Class by JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812975/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-double-type-variable-of-my-class-by-jni)

But, I didn't get the right answer what I want.
Assume I had a java class like:

```
class Data
{
    public Integer value;
}
```

Native:

```
public static native int testGet(Data tdobj);
```

c codes:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
test_jni_Native_testSet(JNIEnv *env, jclass type, jobject tdobj)
{
    jclass tdobjClass = env->FindClass("xxxx/Data");
    jfieldID valueID = env->GetFieldID(tdobjClass, "value", "Ljava/lang/Integer;");
    env->SetIntField(tdobj, jValueID, 123);
    return 0;
}
```

And when I called Native.testGet, the program broke down, and show erro messages as follows:

```
E/dalvikvm: JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale weak global reference 0x7b (index 30 in a table of size 6)
E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 26758
```

I really don't know

How to deal with Double/Integer types in a class, which seems like the same as String ones, but it differs from String type. It seems like that such types can be handled by jobject, but result makes me confused.

Thanks.

***I don't want to use a primitive type like double/int to reach my goal, and I don't want to use functions either. Or you may just tell me that, the way I wished is impossible to reach my goal. Thanks a lot~~***

Comment: "How to deal with Double/Integer types in a class, which seems like the same as String ones, but it differs from String type." While the `Double` and `Integer` types are reference types like `String`, you're not *really* trying to use them in the same way as you are for `String` - you're calling `SetIntField`, which is meant for `int` fields, not `Integer` fields. You can't ignore the difference between primitive types and wrapper types.

Comment: @JonSkeet Then how can I deal with the situation as I described ?

Comment: I don't know - but you shouldn't think about it as being the same as the situation with `String`. (It would have helped if you'd said *why* you didn't want to use functions or use `double`/`int` fields...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Er... I just want to test whether JNI supports the manner of my way to set values of variable.

Comment: @JonSkeet Since I can reach the reference of  a Integer object by jobject, why I can't reach the reference of a Integer object in a java class? Maybe, this is the key problem what I cared.

Comment: @JonSkeet Or, maybe the design of JNI didn't support the way at all, but it makes me confused of "Why not?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, when you get `value` field from `Data` instance, it is not initialized, as your java code shows, so would need to create an instance.

Second, you can't change integer value, you have to instantiate it with the value you want. So, create a new Integer, and then change `value` field from `Data` instance. Something like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL test_jni_Native_testSet(JNIEnv *env, jclass type, jobject tdobj)
{
    //Create Integer class, get constructor and create Integer object
    jclass intClass = env->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
    jmethodID initInt = env->GetMethodID(env, intClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    if (NULL == initInt) return -1;
        jobject newIntObj = env->NewObject(env, intClass, initInt, 123);

    //Now set your integer into value atttribute. For this, I would
    //recommend you to have a java setter and call it in the same way 
    //as shown above

    //clean reference
    env->DeleteLocalRef(env, newIntObj); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I modified the codes to test NULL value like : jobject newIntObj = env->NewObject(env, intClass, initInt, NULL); And it prints "0" in my java code. Since Integer type can be set to "null" value in java, then, how can I set "null" to Integer parameter of my class by JNI ?

Comment: I got that if I new a jobject by jmethodID initInt = env->GetMethodID(env, intClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    if (NULL == initInt) return -1;
        jobject newIntObj = env->NewObject(env, intClass, initInt, NULL); The newIntObj will can't be assigned to NULL but results in 0, does it means "NewObject" will new a integer object no matter the initialized value is what(NULL or valid numbers.).