# How to pass a Java Integer array into C using JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

This page https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html enumerates the data types that JNI handles. For instance, to handle a Java variable of data type `int` the equivalent in JNI is `jint`.

Now if I have a Java variable of data type `Integer`, how can I process this variable in JNI since there is no obvious equivalence for this data type?

Comment: Does this help? [How can I set the value of “Double” type variable of my Class by JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812975/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-double-type-variable-of-my-class-by-jni)

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to treat `Integer` as any other object. You have to find it's method (`intValue`) and call it inside `JNI`

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_recipeNo055_PassObject_passInteger
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass obj, jobject objarg) {

  jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass (env, objarg);

  jmethodID intValue = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "intValue", "()I"); 

  jint result = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, objarg, intValue);

  printf("%-22s: %d\n", "Passed value (int)", result);


}
```

Comment: Thanks @Oo.oO ! Just one last question before I accept this question: do we need to call `DeleteLocalRef` on `objarg` at the end of this code snippet?

Comment: `objarg` will be removed once you leave the scope of the function. Take a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_local and paragraph: `Local References`. If, let's say, you have a loop where you call `GetObjectClass` (on the array of objects) and you create tones of references, it would be probably a good idea to remove them. In this sample, if `jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass (env, objarg)` would have been called numerous times, it would be a good idea to "free" `cls` once each and every iteration of the loop is finished.